# jquery 3.5.1 and tempusdominus datetimepicker not working together

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am using this library:
https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4

But after updating to jquery 3.5.1, I am facing this issue:
https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/164

The datepicker-days are not shown as expected.
Any one having the same issue or might have solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As of today you can use this fork [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tempusdominus-bootstrap) which is updated and compatible with the latest version of jQuery.

The original `tempusdominus/bootstrap-4` is unmaintained and this fork features a set of bugfixes and new features.

### Installation

```
npm i --save tempusdominus-bootstrap tempusdominus
```

### Usage

If you are using ES6, you can use the plugin in your code this way:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import "tempusdominus-bootstrap";

$("#my-datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  // Options...
});
```

If you are using React, you can also check out this library here.